# How to install the mullvard VPN on ubuntu

Tags: internet, vpn, openvpn, privacy

Those are the steps to install MUllvard open vpn

> 1- Using NetworkManager on Ubuntu 16.04 or newer
>
> 2- Open a terminal and issue sudo apt-get install openvpn network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome.
>
> 3- In a browser, navigate to our Configuration files page.
>
> 4- Fill out the form. Under Platform, Android needs to be selected.
>
> 5-Click Download to save the configuration file.
>
> 6-Click on the Network icon.
>
> 7-Click on VPN-Connections > Configure VPN.
>
> 8-Click on Add.
>
> 9-Select Import a saved vpn configuration.
>
> 10-Navigate to where you saved the downloaded file, select it and then click open.
>
> 11-In the user name field, enter your Mullvad account number.
>
> 12-In the password field, enter "m".
>
> 13-Click Save.
>
> 14-Issue sudo nano -w /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and change "dns=dnsmasq" to "#dns=dnsmasq", then save.
>
> 15-Issue sudo service network-manager restart in a terminal.
>
> 16-Click on Network icon > VPN Connections > Mullvad_xx ("xx" is the country you selected to connect).

My question is, what is that 14th step?

Comment: Download and install official Mullvad app it works fine https://mullvad.net/en/download/linux/

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you really need - but you asked about *step 14*

This instructs you to use an editor (suggested: `nano`) to edit the file `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` for which you need `root` permissions (therefore `sudo` is used).

What you should do in that file: find a line

```
dns=dnsmasq
```

and put a `#` at the beginning, which "comments out" the line so that the instruction/option is switched off. In this case this prevents the DNS-resolver from asking/using the service `dnsmasq`.

<sub>the switch `-w` tells `nano` to not insert extra line breaks into the file. See man (1) nano (which you can see by typing `man nano`).</sub>